# How can i get the CPU Usage of the pc and of specific process?

Tags: c#

I want to get the cpu usage of the pc overall usage currently each time lets say every 5 seconds to get updated value of the cpu usage.

And every 5 second to get the value of specific process name cpu usage. For example i will choose in runtime what process to get the cpu usage of.

So in the Form1 when im running the program i will see two labels that are updating every 5 seconds.

This is my code now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace CpuUsage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private PerformanceCounter theCPUCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter theMemCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter specProcessCPUCounter;
        private float cpuUsage;
        private float memUsage;
        private string processname;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


                theCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
                theMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
                specProcessCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
                processname = specProcessCPUCounter.CounterName;
                cpuUsage = this.theCPUCounter.NextValue();
                memUsage = theMemCounter.NextValue();
                label1.Text = memUsage.ToString();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have label1 and label2 in designer.
The value theCPUCounter is 0 all the time.
And i dont know how ot use the specProcessCPUCounter to get the specific process cpuUsage.
And i dont know how to make that they will get update every 5 seconds.

Comment: You do understand that your code runs only once right.  In other words it is doing exactly what its suppose to do.  I have to downvote this question for the lack of research and/or debugging you seem have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a WinForms timer and update the label texts in its `Tick` handler.